# Expressjs - csurf module use inside es6 function undefined

Tags: javascript, express, ecmascript-6

I'm attempting to use csurf module inside my es6 method. I've tried various ways of declaring it for use. Not sure what I'm missing in terms syntax etc.

Any assistance is appreciated.

!--- error

/code/server/api/index.js:46
var csrfProtection1 = csrf({ cookie: true });
                      ^

ReferenceError: csrf is not defined

!------- classs

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import facets from './facets';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import csurf from 'csurf';

let csrfProtection = csrf({ cookie: true });

export default function() {

/*var csrfProtection = csrf({ cookie: true })
var parseForm = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })*/

console.log(csrfProtection); //undefined

var api = Router();

// mount the facets resource
api.use('/facets', facets);

// perhaps expose some API metadata at the root
api.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        version : '1.0'
    });
});

return api;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are importing `csurf` but using `csrf`

It looks like you're missing a letter

To avoid error like that in the future you should use a linter like http://jshint.com/

Comment: oh geez. Time to go to bed I think. I feel really embarrassed right now.